# how to use regex to grab the eighth word

Tags: regex, extract, token

New to Regex
Examples I've seen show searching for very specific exceptions ie. specific letter combos.

What I want is to grab the 8th word no matter what comes before,no matter what those words are.

So the spaces are what designates 'words'

Sample line would be

Sep 20 11:13:18 10.50.3.100 Sep 20 11:13:15 DC1ASM1.dcl.greendotcorp.com Blah Blah Blah

I want to extract the host name, in this case "DC1ASM1.dcl.greendotcorp.com",  which is always preceded by "Month, Day, Timestamp, IP, Month, Day, Timestamp" pattern.

Thanks
Rex

Comment: What language/toolset are you working in? If you have access to a Unix command line, the `cut` utility is built for this, and since it looks like log data that seems likely.

Comment: Thank you Michael. This is python (but through a tool)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what version or flavor of regex you're using, so I'll avoid the look-behind and use a non-capturing group instead:

```
^(?:\S+?\s){7}(\S+)
```

That binds to the beginning of the line, ignores 7 consecutive patterns of *[any character but whitespace] 1+ times] then [one single whitespsace character]*.

You can be more specific about "words" by using `\w` instead of `\S` if you so chose, though.

Comment: +1 for non-capturing group but you shouldn't actually need that `?` because `\S` and `\s` are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1):

This expression will capture the host name in the named group `HostName`. It assumes there are always only single spaces.

```
^([^ ]+ ){7}(?<HostName>[^ ]+)
```

Two handle multiple spaces use the following expression.

```
^([^ ]+ +){7}(?<HostName>[^ ]+)
```

To also support tabs use the following expression.

```
^([^ \t]+[ \t]+){7}(?<HostName>[^ \t]+)
```

Comment: ^([^ ]+ ){7}(?<HostName>[^ ]+)  is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try **something like**:

```
regex = "([^\s]+\s+){7}(?<eighthword>[^\s]+)"
```

Comment: The OP didn't say what regex flavor he's using, so you can't know [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) are available.  Also, `\w+` won't work in this case because some of the words contain "non-word" characters like `.` and `:`.

Comment: Perhaps you can think of it as regex pseudo code if that helps you. Notice the carefully placed 'something like', I've highlighted for your interest. Designed to given an idea. The implementation is left to the interested reader. Thanks for the observation of the \w, however. That was the useful part. Perhaps you'd like to contribute an answer. Could you explain more what named groups are? I think that's something you must know about, since you linked to it.

Comment: Also could you explain the differences in named groups across regex 'flavours?' Since you also appear to know about that useful topic.

Comment: I think the page I linked to does a good job of explaining about named groups; that's why I linked to it.  I only brought it up because, given the introductory level of the question, I didn't think it was safe to assume the OP would recognize named-group syntax when he saw it.  As for contributing my own answer, it would have been virtually identical to [Brad's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13964215/20938), so I upvoted his instead.

Comment: Makes sense. Actually would you be able to link to somewhere that explains that syntax in Brad's. ?:\S+?\s -- I don't understand what the ? do here, or the :. Also, I just had an idea I want to write a project that explain in plain english what any regex you feed it is doing. Do you think this would be a good idea/useful? You seem to be the go-to guy for regex.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is very very helpful. I'm not actually sure what flavor of regex is being used (I'm working with Splunk so perl/python centric regex). But since thinking in "Regex Head" is new to me - this is all golden. I'll try it out and then pipe up if I need to tweak it.  Very grateful for the assist.  - Rex

Comment: Regex Flavor is Python.  And Chris... I'd buy the translator. It would be like "Spell check" for regex.